# How to update json null value using jsonb_set

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a nested json object. I want to use `jsonb_set` to update value of a property that currently is null. I have tried following.

```
UPDATE database1
SET foo = jsonb_set(foo, '{"bar",0}', '"TEST1"', true)
WHERE foo #> '{"bar",0}' is null
```

This is not working, this solution works if the value is not null.

Comment: Ok I got the answer. This is what I did.                                         
         UPDATE database1
         SET foo = jsonb_set(foo, '{"bar"}', '["TEST1"]', true)
         WHERE foo #> '{"bar",0}' is null